# Change webdrivers ip when it starts

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I want change webdriver’s ip and display it on console when i start code.

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(<any link>)

# Code for change webdriver’s ip. I need help for there. 

print(“Your current ip = “ + “<Webdriver’s new ip>“)
```

Comment: did you want to know how to configure a proxy for the browser to use?  Or are you talking about the IP of selenium server/hub?

Comment: Yeah, actually I need configure a proxy to use. But I need different proxies i mean I need change my proxy when i start code. Because Some websites blocks me if i created a lot of accounts and i need use vpn :(